# Bootstrap btn height with tomcat

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tomcat, frontend

I'm working to front end with AngularJS, so i decided to use Bootstrap. In my page sometimes i use `class="btn"` (because i need some buttons) but i have seen one difference in runtime. 
***I explain the problem here.*** 
When i test my application in XAMPP (while developing) everything is good, without problem, but when i copy my files to my web dynamic project (i use spring) in runtime i see reduced height of buttons. Anyone has the same problem? i hope this was not duplicate of question, but i didn't what to search.
Here you can see what i means -->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrdyC.jpg

Comment: Use your browser's development console, select one of your buttons and go to Styles tab / section. Look for the styles applied to your element and find the reason of the problem.

Comment: I have seen, "height: 16px" but not builded (i have added the img)

Comment: line-height is whats changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `height: 24px;` in `.btn-xs` css class